# MVC3 jQuery.validate not working when submitting form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been working in MVC3 using the built in jquery validation.

Client validation did appear to be working when tabbing through the fields except when I submitted the actual form.

Below are my include scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I managed to fix this by reverting the jquery version to jquery-1.4.4.min.js so I'm just wondering:

Isn't jquery backwards compatible? Also - why would the validation actually work but just fail when an input submits?

Could this be a bug in the new version of jQuery?

Comment: jQuery's `.attr()` function was changed in 1.6.  Since unobtrusive validations read `data-*` attributes, I wouldn't doubt that it's broken.  I have an example MVC application available on github (which uses jQuery 1.5.1) See: [here](https://github.com/jimschubert/ContainsAttributeExample)

Answer (score 2):

At first it seemed to me like jQuery 1.6 would break compatibility.  It turned out it was just a little trickier to get unobtrusive validation working than I thought.  This is a good tutorial that'll get you a working example:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

You can then switch to jquery 1.6.2 and see that it's still working.  For me, what was missing from my nearly identical view was Html.BeginForm.  Once I added that, everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug and there is no solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form posting? If not you may have a validation rule that's being violated but you may not see the error message if you don't have Html.ValidationSummary or Html.ValidationMessageFor enabled.

**EDIT:

I tried with the latest version of jQuery (1.6.4) and with 1.6.2 with this code without any issues.

controller code

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string textTest { get; set; }

[Required]
public int intTest { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TestViewModel());
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

}

markup

```
@model MvcApplication39.Controllers.TestViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>ViewBag.Title</h2>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>TestViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.textTest)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.textTest)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.textTest)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.intTest)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.intTest)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.intTest)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the form is posting but it's empty and therefore it should be being caught client side. But.. if I type characters into a numerical field the client validation kicks in..

I fixed this by changing the jquery version back to 1.4.4 but I think it should work with the newest version of jquery?

Comment: Weird, I haven't seen any issues. Anyway you can post the markup and model?

Comment: If you just try any model with a simple required attribute on a property and include the same script files I mentioned above you should be able to replicate the problem quite easily..

you'll notice that a submit posts.. but if you change the jquery version from jquery-1.6.2.min.js to jquery-1.4.4.min.js it works.

Comment: That's bizarre. I have my project here. I am referencing 1.6.2 which is when it posts back. I then switch to 1.4.4 and it validates on the client. hmmmm.

The version of jquery I was referencing was downloaded from the jQuery ui site but I assume it's the usual release version..

Comment: As far as I can tell, jQuery 1.6.2 is not supported by the unobtrusive validation stuff.  I have yet to find a solution.